# BeautifulSoup returns gibberish

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse a website with BeautifulSoup:

```
name="Sai"
url="https://www.babynamesdirect.com/baby-names/indian/boy/begins/"+name
babynamespage=urlopen(url)
pagesoup=BeautifulSoup(babynamespage,"html.parser")
print(pagesoup)
```

When I do this, instead of seeing the full HTML tags, I'm seeing this:

```
**Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.**
      �]_��6��]wN�F�����챝x�k;q���DB$��h4�;��^�7���
&amp;�{2�   ��g#�   �?���1&\
```

What's this gibberish?
How to rectify this?

Comment: What is the `page` you are using ? An url ? A file ?

Comment: Its a URL, not a page.

Comment: Ok, then please add the definition of `page` to your post.

Comment: yup, just did that. Thanks!

Comment: As you are using another variable in the definition of `url`, you should either add the definition of that variable to your post, too, or hardcode it (write `url="https://www.babynamesdirect.com/baby-names/indian/boy/begins/somename"` instead). Additionally, please post the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.getdefaultencoding());"`

Comment: utf-8 is the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try using requests along with beautiful soup.  The requests will get the data, the beautiful soup will process the text that comes back from the data.

```
# try this once
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://www.babynamesdirect.com/baby- 
names/indian/boy/a')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
print(soup)
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works!
Could you tell me what mistakes did I do?

Comment: could you explain more, please?

Comment: also, why is your timeout at 3.05 and 27?

Comment: I just removed that timeout it will work without that too